Running Laravel Octane/Swoole with IP host
I am currently running Laravel project with Octane and Swoole. It works well on localhost, but whenever I try to run Laravel Octane with host I always got an error like that:
Running Laravel Octane on localhost
Running Laravel Octane with IP host
What configuration am I missing to running Laravel Octane with IP host?

hm, it's missing class
please try remove vendor and reinstall composer install and composer dump-autoload

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
